# What is alternative to use customised alert views in ios7?

Tags: ios6, ios7, uialertview

in ios6 I had UITextfield placed on UIAlertview to take inputs from user.
but in ios7 it don't seem to be working.
Any idea how to achieve that in ios7?

Thanks,
Virat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same task I'm creating `UIView` subclasses that I add as subviews to the main `window`. This way they will appear on top of everything and I'm in control of the layout & functionality.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. will follow the same approach.